# Vanishing periodizations $\sum_{k \in \mathbb Z} f(t+ak)$ of a function $f$ for different values of $a$ implies $f=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-analysis, periodic-functions, periods

Consider a continuous function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ with rapid decay (e.g. $|f(t)| < e^{-t^2}$). For a constant $a>0$ let
$$
F_a(t) = \sum_{k \in \mathbb Z} f(t+ak)
$$
be the periodization of $f$ with period $a$. Assume that $F_a = 0$, that is, $F_a$ vanishes identically. In general, this does *not* imply that $f$ vanishes identically. How about $F_a = 0$ for different values of $a$? Formally, assume that
$$
F_{a_1} = F_{a_2} = \dotsb =  F_{a_n} = 0\tag{$*$}\label{star}
$$
for different $a_j >0$. Can we find conditions on the $a_j$'s so that \eqref{star} implies $f=0$?

Comment: Is it obvious that $F_a = 0$ for *all* $a > 0$ implies $F = 0$?

Comment: No for now that's also not obvious to me. Actually I'm also wondering what happens if  the $a$'s belong to an interval, $a \in (x,y)$ where $x<y$. Would this be enough to conclude that $f=0$?

Comment: For $n = 2$ the ratio $a_1 / a_2$ should be irrational, right ?

Answer (score 4):

The Fourier coefficients of the periodic function $F_a$ are (up to a factor)
\begin{align*}
\int_0^a F_a(t) e^{2\pi in t/a}\, dt & =\sum_k \int_0^a f(t+ak)e^{2\pi int/a}\, dt\\
& = \sum_k \int_{ka}^{(k+1)a} f(s) e^{2\pi ins/a}\, ds \\
& = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(s)e^{2\pi i ns/a}\, ds .
\end{align*}
So the condition $F_a=0$ is equivalent to $\widehat{f}$ vanishing on $(1/a)\mathbb Z$, and no finite set of such conditions can imply that $f=0$.

Comment: It's not clear to me if the last conclusion follows or not. It might be the case that the inequality $|f(t)|<e^{-t^2}$ prevents its Fourier transform from vanishing on a large set of lattices (which will imply, for instance, lots of very closely spaced zeros).

Comment: @MarkLewko The OP did not specify what they meant by "rapid decay". Certainly in the Schwartz space $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ there is a nonzero function whose Fourier transform vanishes at a prescribed discrete subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @GHfromMO I took the inequality from the problem statement! That said, I agree if the condition is just Schwartz this is correct.

Comment: @MarkLewko Yes, but perhaps you missed the "e.g." in front of the inequality.

Comment: For the decay in "e.g." we may choose $\widehat{f}(t) = e^{-b t^2} \prod_{i=1}^n sin(\pi t a_i)$ with sufficient small $b > 0$ .

Comment: @MarkLewko: If $|f(t)|\lesssim e^{-t^2}$ was your interpretation of the question, then in fact what you suggest in your answer can be improved. In that case, $\widehat{f}$ is entire, so we only need $\{ n/a_j\}$ to have an accumulation point somewhere to conclude that $f=0$.

Comment: @GHfromMO How do you construct a function in the Schwartz space with a prescribed (discrete) sequence of zeros? I do not see it immediately.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune Take any closed interval disjoint from the sequence, and then take a (not identically zero) smooth function supported in that interval. This function will be in the Schwartz class and vanish at the given sequence.

Comment: @GHfromMO True, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

From Poisson summation, you have that
$$F_a(t) = \frac{1}{a} \sum_{n \in Z} \widehat{f}(n/a)e(tn/a).$$
Further we know that $F_a(t)$ will identically vanish if and only if the Fourier coefficients identically vanish. This leaves you with a question about zeros of the Fourier transform of a rapidly decaying function.

It follows from this that such a set of $a_i$'s, say $A$ will suffice as long a you can guarantee that for some $\xi$ such that $\widehat{f}(\xi) \neq 0$ there is an $a \in A$ such that $\xi a \in Z$. Clearly, for instance, answering the question from the comments, $A=R^{+}$ will suffice.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no.

Proof by induction :

Let $f_n \neq 0$ with compact support such that the periodizations of $a_1,...,a_n$ are zero.
Then there exists an integer $m$ such that the function $f_{n+1}(x) = f_n(x) - f_n(x + m a_{n+1})$ is non zero.
But for $f_{n+1}$ the periodizations of $a_1,...,a_{n+1}$ are zero and $f_{n+1}$ has also compact support.